# Keeping text formatting while extracting long text from SAP GUI with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I would like to retrieve a text that is displayed in SAP GUI with a macro that extracting it. I already have the macro that does that. It clicks on the button on the right of Line 1 like so:

[image]

And then it displays the texts like so :
[image]

It copies it, and pastes it in a cell.

However, Once in the cell the text is displayed this way :

```
Test 1 is ok Test 2 is nok Test 3 is nok
```

but I want it to keep the exact same formatting like this :

```
Test 1 is ok
Test 2 is nok
Test 3 is nok
```

Any idea on how I could make this happen ?

Comment: What is the macro? Also, your links are broken so we don't have much to go on here.

Comment: Oups well the pictures are displayed fine for me. I'm gonna check what is going on

Comment: Actually they're working now. Not sure if it was an issue on my end. Maybe you should try wrapping the text in double quotes so excel formats the CR/LF characters?

Comment: @JacobH this is actually how I get the text `text = .findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSCMSW_CONTAINER_2102/shellcont/shell").document.Content.text`

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found the solution by putting a spy.

```
k = 1
           Text = ""
           Do
           If .findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSCMSW_CONTAINER_2102/shellcont/shell").document.Words(k).Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Long text").Cells(1, 10).Value Then
           Text = Text & Chr(10)
           Else
           Text = Text & .findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSCMSW_CONTAINER_2102/shellcont/shell").document.Words(k).Text
           End If
           k = k + 1
           Loop Until k = .findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSCMSW_CONTAINER_2102/shellcont/shell").document.Words.Count + 1
```